# I have a question about setting a variable "random" to a function to receive a random number between 1- whatever the user input

Tags: javascript

In the console, I checked that my variable `maxAge`, is set to the input of the user in the first box.

Then I checked my function `getRandomInt` worked, and truly get a random number between 1- whatever the user put in box.

For some reason that I don't understand I can't set a variable called
`randomAge = getRandomInt()`
Can someone explain to me why?
html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">

  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Guses The Age.
    From 1 - <span id="secretage"></span>
  </h1>
<p id="massageDisplay"></p>

<br>
  <input id="gusesInput" type="number">
  <input id="numInput" type="number">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

js

```js
var min = 1
var userInput = document.querySelector("#numInput")
var userGuses = document.querySelector("#gusesInput")
var randomAge = getRandomInt()

userInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
  maxAge = Number(this.value)
  ageDisplay.textContent = maxAge
})

function getRandomInt() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxAge - min)) + min;
}

// save random age as variable
```

Comment: Well, you don't ever reference `randomAge` anywhere in your code... What are you expecting to happen with that? Also, you don't define `maxAge` outside of the `"change"` event listener function, so it's undefined in the `getRandomInt` function. Please add relevant HTML to the Stack Snippet I added to your post so that others can reproduce the issue. Also, tell us what the issue is.

Comment: yea , when i edited the question the website said DONT POST THE WHOLE CODE!

Comment: Right, don't post the whole code, just the relevant HTML. So, the elements with ids "numInput" and "gusesInput" and whatever `ageDisplay` refers to.

Comment: k i added the html . but im confused about how i can save something that the user put inside the Input box  make a  random number 1-whatevertheuserinput and put that as random age

Answer (score 0):

```
// min and max can be set in (randomAge) closure var min=1
var userInput=document.querySelector("#numInput")
var userGuses=document.querySelector("#gusesInput")
/*
this assigns your function to the variable but it does not trigger the function. 

var randomAge=getRandomInt()
*/

var randomAge = (function (){
    var min = 0,
          max = 0,
          age = 0;

    function setMinFunc(newNum){
        return min = newNum;
    }
    function setMaxFunc(newNum){
        return max = newNum;
    }
    function setRandomFunc(){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min )) + min;
    }
    function getAgeFunc(newNum){
        return age;
    }
    function checkValsFunc(){
        console.log('min value is ', min, '. max value is ', max, '. age is ', age);
    }

    return{
        setMin: setMinFunc,
        setMax: setMaxFunc,
        setRandom: setRandomFunc,
        gatAge: getAgeFunc,
        checkVals: checkValsFunc
    }
}());

  randomAge.setMin(1);


userInput.addEventListener("change",function(){

      maxAge=Number(this.value)
      ageDisplay.textContent=maxAge
      randomAge.setMax(maxAge);
               randomAge.setRandom();
               randomAge.checkVals();
    })

// you can retrieve your random value by assigning it to a variable like this.

var myRandomVal = randomAge.gatAge();
```

Comment: `var randomAge=getRandomInt()` does not assign the function to the variable. It assigns the result of the function call to the variable... Also, this seems overengineered for such a simple problem (if indeed there is a problem; the OP hasn't said what the problem is).

Comment: well when i wanted to post the whole code, there was a comment said DONT PosT THE WHOLE CODE! haha.. well i think i figured out how to do it. my main problem really was just assigning my random function to a variable, and that random range 1-maxAge will be set by the user. that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are missing many points in order for your code to work:

- In the `getRandomInt()` function, `maxAge` is not defined. This variable should be declared at the same time of all other ones. But I suggest you to use two function parameters to have a minimum and maximum limit.
- You are trying to attribute the returned result of `getRandomInt()` to `randomAge` but as `maxAge` is not defined outside your event handler... Moreover, if it was the case, `randomAge` would never change as you are not executing it in your event handler. You need to just define it at the beginning (at `0` for example), and to attribute the result call at change of your input.

Here is below a snippet that should work, with the corrections I suggested. I commented the changes I made, and the lines which are not useful **for the snippet**.

```js
var min = 1;
var userInput = document.querySelector("#numInput");
//var userGuses = document.querySelector("#gusesInput");
var randomAge = 0; // Initializes here your random int variable.

userInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
  maxAge = Number(this.value);
  //ageDisplay.textContent = maxAge;
  
  randomAge = getRandomInt(min, maxAge); // Attributes your random age to the variable.
  console.log(randomAge);
})

// Added here two parameters for MIN and MAX integer.
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="numInput" min="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var min = 1
var userInput = document.querySelector("#numInput")
var userGuses = document.querySelector("#gusesInput")
var randomAge ;
var maxAge;


userInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
  maxAge = Number(this.value)
  ageDisplay.textContent = maxAge
//should set the value in function 
randomAge = getRandomInt();
//check the random value in console 
console.log(randomAge);
})

function getRandomInt() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxAge - min)) + min;
}

// save random age as variable
```

i added this part of code in input event Listerine to get random value som missing like you should define maxAge
    //should set the value in function 
    //randomAge = getRandomInt();
    //check the random value in console 
    //console.log(randomAge);